# Scanner not detected - invalid argument

Tags: 14.04, networking, scanner, brother

It seems my Brother MFC-9120-CN is not detected whenever I want to scan an image.
The printer works fine, however. The device is directly connected in my local network.

```
➜  ~  scanimage -L
device `brother3:net1;dev0' is a Brother MFC-9120CN SCANNER_BROTHER
➜  ~  scanimage --test
scanimage: open of device brother3:net1;dev0 failed: Invalid argument
➜  ~  scanimage           
scanimage: open of device brother3:net1;dev0 failed: Invalid argument
```

Same result with simple-scan.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem and just stumbled upon this solution https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simple-scan/+bug/848575/comments/3

Brother provides packages `brscan`, `brscan2`, `brscan3`, ..., which contain necessary drivers. Unfortunately, the shared libraries (drivers) are stored below `/usr/lib64` and `/usr/lib64/sane`, but scanimage tries to load them from `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib/sane`.

So, the solution is to copy or link these files to the proper directories

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother* /usr/lib/sane
ln -s /usr/lib64/libbrscandec* /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/lib64/libbrcolm* /usr/lib
```

The 32 bit version doesn't have this problem, because the shared objects are stored in the correct location.

Comment: Wow, this was it. 7 years later and no one has fixed the bug.

Comment: @nitro2k01 Well, the real solution at launchpad is even older, 11 years ago. So, I would assume, that HP won't fix this anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Olaf Dietsche needs to be modified a bit for Mint 19.1 and Ubuntu 18.04. One can use

```
strace -e openat scanimage > /dev/null
```

to find where it's looking for libraries. In this case, it looks for `libbrscandec3.so` in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, `/lib`, and `/usr/lib`.

Hence, run these commands as root:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
ln -vs /usr/lib64/libbrscandec*.so* .
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
ln -vs /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother*.so* .
```

This should work for brscan3-based scanners. Other brscan versions may have slightly different library filenames; for brscan4, check the output of

```
dpkg -L brscan4 | grep \\.so
```

to see which library files are installed and need to be linked. For brscan4, the `libbrscandec` files are not need; for brscan2, `libbrcolm2` is needed in addition to `libbrscandec`.

Answer (score -1):

To see result you ought to type in terminal next:

```
scanimage -d brother3:net1:dev0 --resolution 150 --mode Color --format=tiff > /tmp/test.tif
```

P.S. Don't forget to put some paper into scanner to be scanned. Then you see result of scanning into /tmp/test.tif file.